# How to automatic search and replace for 18n.properties file with WebStorm

Tags: internationalization, sapui5, webstorm

For SAPUI5 there are `i18n.properties` files.

For the German language I need to replace the special German chars with the unicode codes.

```
# AE = \u00C4, ae = \u00E4
# OE = \u00D6, oe = \u00F6
# UE = \u00DC, ue = \u00FC
# SZ = \u00DF
```

How can I automate this search and replace with WebStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use WebStorms 'Replace in Path' (CMD+SHIFT+R on Mac) on your i18n folder. IntelliJ IDEA has better editing support for .properties files though (since they are coming from java)

Will be also easy to do this via a node script/bash script/gulp task whatsoever.

Btw: Is this really needed? Having all .properties files in `UTF-8` should just do the trick. Afaik only Tomcat got confused by that since in the Java spec these files are `ISO-8859-1` by definition. As long as you are deploying to a platform that accepts them as UTF-8 there shouldn't be an issue.

BR
Chris

PS: That code looks really familiar ;D

Comment: hoped that webstorm would have a solution for that. So the script/task way would be the way to go.